# Unmute sound for android

Tags: java, android, audio

I have an app in which i implemented a switch button to toggle audio on and off. I understand very well that using `adjustStreamVolume`only works for api 23 and above while `setStreamMute`is deprecated so i handled by logic appropriately.
However, i am having issue with audio state for device api's lower than api 23 as it does not unmute after bein previously muted. The switch and audio state works well anyways for api 23 and above but i need help on how to properly mute and unmute device for device api's lower than 23.
Here is my logic.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Switch mSoundSwitch;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    AudioManager aManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSoundSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.soundSwitch);
        sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSoundSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if (isChecked) {
    unmute();
    sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sound", true);
    editor.apply();

} else {
   mute();
    sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sound", false);
    editor.apply();

}
            }
        });
           // retrieving value from shared preferences (sound)
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound", true);
        mSoundSwitch.setChecked(isChecked);

    }
    private void mute() {
        //mute audio
        aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            aManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        } else {
            aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
        }
    }

    public void unmute() {
        //unmute audio
        aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            aManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
        } else {
            aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
 private void mute() {
        //mute audio
        aManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            aManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
        } else {
           aManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void unmute() {
        //unmute audio
        aManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            aManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
        } else {
            aManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When performing unmute, does not the stream music volume restores to full instead of last set volume? - How did you fixed this issue?